# How would you design an AppEngine datastore for a social site like Twitter?

Tags: google-app-engine, architecture, google-cloud-datastore

I'm wondering what would be the best way to design a social application where members make activities and follow other member's activities using Google AppEngine.

To be more specific lets assume we have these entities:

- **Users** who have friends
- **Activities** which represent actions made by users (lets say each has a string message and a ReferenceProperty to its owner user, or it can use parent association via appengine's key)

The hard part is following your friend's activities, which means aggregating the latest activities from all your friends.
Normally, that would be a join between the Activities table and your friends list but thats not a viable design on appengine as there are no join simulating it will require firing up N queries (where N is number of friends) and then merging in memory - very expensive and will probably exceed request deadline...)

I'm currently thinking of implementing this using inbox queues where creation of a new Activity will fire a background process that will put the new activity's key in the "inbox" of every following user:

- Getting "All the users who follow X" is a possible appengine query
- Not a very expensive batch input into a new "Inbox" entity that basically stores (User, Activity Key) tuples.

I'll be happy to heard thought on this design or alternative suggestions etc.

Comment: I was looking at the same problem and found this excellent(!) presentation from the AppEngine, which they gave at Google I/O: http://www.scribd.com/doc/16952419/Building-scalable-complex-apps-on-App-Engine I hope you'll find it useful too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look at [Building Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html) ([pdf](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16952419/Building-scalable-complex-apps-on-App-Engine)), a fascinating talk given at Google I/O by Brett Slatkin. He addresses the problem of building a scalable messaging service like Twitter.

Here's his **solution** using a list property:

```
class Message(db.Model):
    sender = db.StringProperty()
    body = db.TextProperty()

class MessageIndex(db.Model):
    #parent = a message
    receivers = db.StringListProperty()

indexes = MessageIndex.all(keys_only = True).filter('receivers = ', user_id)
keys = [k.parent() for k in indexes)
messages = db.get(keys)
```

This key only query finds the message indices with a receiver equal to the one you specified without deserializing and serializing the list of receivers. Then you use these indices to only grab the messages that you want.

Here's **the wrong way** to do it:

```
class Message(db.Model):
    sender = db.StringProperty()
    receivers = db.StringListProperty()
    body = db.TextProperty()

messages = Message.all().filter('receivers =', user_id)
```

This is inefficient because queries have to unpackage all of the results returned by your query. So if you returned 100 messages with 1,000 users in each receivers list you'd have to deserialize 100,000 (100 x 1000) list property values. Way too expensive in datastore latency and cpu.

I was pretty confused by all of this at first, so I wrote up a [short tutorial about using the list property](http://www.gomuse.com/google-app-engine-using-the-list-property-dbl). Enjoy :)

Comment: Exactly my initial design. But what I understood from that talk and from the AppEngine documentation is that lists are pretty useless when in comes to IN queries.
The query you mentioned will fire several queries in google system, each filtering by one of the values in the list properties and then merge the result.
Google caps this kind of query to 30 simultaneous queries which means it can only be used for list who will contain relatively small number of Keys (<30). 
When it comes to friends, this list could contain tens if not hundreds (or thousands?) of keys for people you're following.

Comment: btw I asked you that same question regarding lists in another StackOverflow question you posted :)

Comment: I don't think that's right. Brett says that you're limited to 5000 indexed properties per entity when he's talking about list property performance (see 14:15 in the video). I think you should be able to have thousands of users in a receivers StringListProperty, while still being able to perform an efficient query. I'm not sure what the line "A single query containing != or IN operators is limited to 30 sub-queries" means, but I positive it doesn't affect what you want to do here.

Comment: What is the difference between GQL IN operator (which according to docs limited to 30 items) and the filter used here (which according to the presentation will work for large lists) ?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Nick Johnson would probably know; if he doesn't show up here try asking this in the app engine group http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine

Or you could just try it out. I mean, if it actually works and has decent performance that's all that matters.

Comment: Just went over the presentation againand had my "A-Ha!" moment!  thanks... this is exactly the solution I need. and instead of saving a Friends list in User entity I should save a "followed by" (recipients)...

Comment: 'IN' is "find any entity containing one of these values", which gets split out into n "find any entity containing this exact value" queries. An equality filter on a list, however, is the latter - "find any entity that has this exact value (possibly in a list)", and so isn't inefficient in the same way an IN query is.

Comment: @wings What happens when you make a new connection? You need to see all of the messages that your new connection posted previously, but that would require updating the receivers list for each message, seems expensive.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know whether it is the *best* design for a social application, but [jaiku](http://www.jaiku.com) was [ported to App Engine](http://jaikido.blogspot.com/2008/04/wroom-were-moving-to-google-app-engine.html) by it's original creator when the company was acquired by Google, so it should be reasonable.

See the section *Actors and Tigers and Bears, Oh My!* in [design_funument.txt](http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/source/browse/trunk/doc/design_funument.txt). The entities are defined in [common/models.py](http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/source/browse/trunk/common/models.py) and the queries are in [common/api.py](http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/source/browse/trunk/common/api.py).

Answer (score 1):

Robert, about your proposed solution:

```
messages = Message.query(Message.receivers == user_id).fetch(projection=[Message.body])
```

I think the ndb.TextProperty "body" can't be used with projections because is not indexed. Projections only support indexed properties.
The valid solution would be to maintain the 2 tables: Message and MessageIndex.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can now be solved with the new Projection Queries in NDB.

```
class Message(ndb.Model):
    sender = ndb.StringProperty()
    receivers = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    body = ndb.TextProperty()

messages = Message.query(Message.receivers == user_id).fetch(projection=[Message.body])
```

Now you don't have to deal with the expensive cost of deserializing the list property.