# AppEngine datastore design advice required

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am building a distributed accounting system.
In terms of the DB structure and requirements, it's probably easiest to describe the app as a Twitter-like app, but with a hierarchical DB structure of 14 tables.
A company that uses the app may have 1 and more users, all sharing the company information.

Currently, each entity represents a record type, i.e. customers, invoices etc.
All entities have a parent which is the user of the app. (for HRD query consistency reasons)

Each query to the DB consists of 14 AppEngine queries. One for each table.
The query involves property filtering.

A new requirement is that a query of a user may require different property values based on each of the other users.
This means that we need (14 x the number of company-users) AppEngine queries. This seems far too much.

Kindless Ancestor queries that can filter by properties would be really nice, alas, no can do :)

My options are:

1. Set entity kind to User. No parent. This means that all record types are mixed. (The filtered fields exist in all record types).
   This is not pretty. But would you consider that?
2. Have a fixed entity kind and query by filter only. The result is the equivalent of the Kindless Ancestor queries. However, I fear that it will be slow in a multi user use.

Some numbers:
We plan for 10,000 companies, average of 5 users per company and 1 to 5 million records per record type. (x 14 for total)

Thank you for your patience so far.. :)

Comment: Why does each query require querying all the tables? This seems like a very odd requirement.

Comment: @Nick, the application has a distributed DB. Each client has a local copy of the DB with information relevant to that client. Each query needs to find all new/changed info in the entire DB and transfer the data to the client for local use. (each query will find changes in almost all of the tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I found it challenging to follow your description, so this may be off base. Seeing your existing code might help. But I get that you want an efficient alternative to propertied kindless ancestor queries, so let's start there.

Consider de-normalizing your data model to include a meta-entity just for querying:

```
class User(db.Model):
  pass

class OwnedObject(db.Expando):
  object_key = db.StringProperty()

class Customer(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  created_on = db.DateProperty()

class Invoice(db.Model):
  amount = db.IntegerProperty()
  created_on = db.DateProperty()

# on write
customer = Customer()
customer.name = name
customer.created_on = date.today()
customer.put()

user = User(key_name=users.get_current_user().user_id())

owned_object = OwnedObject(parent=user)
owned_object.object_key = customer.key()
owned_object.created_on = customer.created_on
owned_object.put()

# on read
query = OwnedObject.all()
query.ancestor(user)
query.filter('created_on =', date.today())

entities = db.get([x.object_key for x in query])
```

So here you're doing more work on write and less on read.

Each real entity is coupled with an OwnedObject entity that descends from the appropriate ancestor and points to the real entity's key. OwnedObject is an expando, so you'll eager-assign any properties that you want to query on (in this example, created_on).

On read, you can query for any properties that you've copied to the expando meta-entity, and you can pull back all of a user's objects with a fixed overhead of one query and one batch get.

**Edit**: You can accomplish something similar without the meta-entity by using [PolyModel](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass.html).

Comment: Thanks @Drew. You understood my question 100%.  Compared to my solution option 1 (in the body of the question), your solution has the advantage of keeping the base entities in a manageable 'Entity per record type'. The disadvantage is adding the overhead of maintaining the meta-entity and the two-step read. Do you believe it's worth it? Is a messy entity like in option 1 is a big no-no? What's your opinion?

Comment: I guess your example in using jdo which I am not familiar with, but I believe I got the idea. How does jdo implement the last line (db.get([...])? I guess jdo issues multiple db.get() under the hood since the platform IN() is limited to 30 items. (going to read PolyModel)

Comment: I guess my first guess was wrong. It's Python :) (I use java + native AppEngine classes). PolyModel does not seem to fit my DB design. It does naturally handles data of a similar kind (inheritance). Expando on the other hand, is a way to implement my solution option 1.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I assumed Python sans evidence. I do think de-normalization is the right approach here. Disk is cheap and CPU is expensive. If you're not convinced, try both and use AppStats to compare results. Remember that you pay for extra disk usage once (per cycle), but you pay for inefficient queries in CPU time and delayed page loads on every single request.

Comment: Thanks @Drew. I have found that db.get([x.object_key for x in query]) is implemented very efficiently as a parallel get of a List. This make your solution more appealing in terms of CPU overhead. I'll be doing some more research and be back. Thanks again. (voted up as a good viable solution)

Comment: Hi @Drew. I've adopted your solution and I would only add one optimization to your solution in line of what is proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630087/how-would-you-design-an-appengine-datastore-for-a-social-site-like-twitter).